# How to install Bumblebee in Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, bumblebee

I found Nvidia drivers freezes in Cinnamon or their Cinnamon crash or run in fall-back mode.

As Bumblebee works better, how can I install Bumblebee in Linux Mint 17?

Comment: This question in hard to read, and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/549916) to install bumblebee on my mint 17.2 
and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the nvidia drivers might just need to be updated. As of late 2016 many people are having problems with the the 367 drivers that are available in the standard repo, but I've gotten the 375 drivers to work with the current linux mint version 18.1, and further gotten Prime and Bumblebee to allow me to switch between my embedded Intel card and my Nvidia card (Prime), or do so at runtime for a particular application (Bumblebee).

Note that the latest nvidia drivers may require adding the ppa to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

This page is quite useful for troubleshooting:

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting